# windows 10 microphone monitoring

Tags: windows, operating-system, kernel, system-calls, utility

I am trying to build an application for windows 10 to inform me when a process starts using my microfone. I tried to inspect opened files (handlers) with ProcessExplorer but it doesn't give me any specific information about which handler corresponds to my default sound input. What I am trying to do is almost what windows 10 already does when it puts a mic icon on system tray whenever a process open my microfone. I am hoping someone who have some knowledge on how windows sub systems works could shed some light into this. Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate more so others can understand?

Comment: I need to write a code to find out which processes are using my microphone. I know how to do it in linux, but windows seems to mask physical devices mapping.